# How to get CssFriendly working with IE11 on ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, internet-explorer-11

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms application which uses the CSSFriendly control adaptors to spit out more modern HTML. However, since the recent release IE11, it is no longer working for this browser, and the control adaptors are not being used - no error message to say that [it is at least trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079174/ie10-ie-browser-fix-doesnt-work-with-cssfriendlyadapters). The website is [not pre-compiled](http://conficient.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/fix-for-precompiled-websites-from-vs2010-on-net-3-5-for-cssfriendly-adapters/). For added good luck, the application runs on Server 2003, so installing .NET Framework 4.5 isn't going to help much.

I have tried [updating the browser definition file](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/incorrectly-rendered-webpage-when-using-internet-explorer-11.aspx), but this makes no difference.

Chrome, Safari and Firefox all trigger the control adaptors.

Comment: Have you tried `App_Browsers` file in your project.

Comment: Yes, as per the link to http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/incorrectly-rendered-webpage-when-using-internet-explorer-11.aspx above.